# How to use Oracle's LISTAGG function with a unique filter?

Tags: oracle, group-by, oracle11g, aggregate-functions

I have a table like this:

```
group_id  name  
--------  ----
1         David
1         John
1         Alan
1         David
2         Julie
2         Charles
```

And I want the following result:

```
group_id  names
--------  -----
1         'Alan, David, John'
2         'Charles, Julie'
```

I can use the following query:

```
select group_id, 
       listagg(name, ',') within group (order by name) as names
from demotable
group by group_id
```

To get this (very similar result):

```
group_id  names
--------  -----
1         'Alan, David, David, John'
2         'Charles, Julie'
```

Any ideas how I can filter the names by uniqueness in the `LISTAGG` call?

Comment: Check out the accepted answer in this post:

http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/696/eliminate-duplicates-in-listagg-oracle

Comment: It isn't quite the same..  Answers that work for this question need to be revamped to answer the other question.  That isn't to say you can't learn something there to apply to this problem..

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I don't have an 11g instance available today but could you not use:

```
SELECT group_id,
       LISTAGG(name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name) AS names
  FROM (
       SELECT UNIQUE
              group_id,
              name
         FROM demotable
       )
 GROUP BY group_id
```

Comment: That was my first thought, on this question and looking at the linked DBA question. On this simple data the cost is the same according to autotrace.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is correct for the problem. Unfortunately, I was not precise enough in my question formulation and it doesn't help with my real life issue because there are other columns I need from this table that I can't hide with a `UNIQUE` operator.

Comment: Nice - painful but it works. You should see the query I have that this is but a small piece of :D oh what a tangled web we weave :D

Answer (score 18):

Super simple answer - solved!

my full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510870/listagg-in-oracle-to-return-distinct-values/22624072#22624072) it is now built in in some oracle versions.

```
select group_id, 
regexp_replace(
    listagg(name, ',') within group (order by name)
    ,'([^,]+)(,\1)*(,|$)', '\1\3')
from demotable
group by group_id;
```

This only works if you specify the delimiter to ',' not ', ' ie 
works only for no spaces after the comma. If you want spaces after the comma - here is a example how.

```
select 
replace(
    regexp_replace(
     regexp_replace('BBall, BBall, BBall, Football, Ice Hockey ',',\s*',',')            
    ,'([^,]+)(,\1)*(,|$)', '\1\3')
,',',', ') 
from dual
```

gives 
BBall, Football, Ice Hockey

Comment: I've used Oracle regexp for a bit but I'm not an expert and I have no clue what's going on here, especially the "\1" in the pattern string.
Can someone please explain what's happening here?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work for me if the repeated value isn't the first 2 values in the listagg result.

For example: this list of sports works (where Baseball is duplicated): Baseball, Basketball - Men, Football, Ice Hockey - Men
But this doesn't: Field Hockey, Ultimate Frisbee Club - Women, Ultimate Frisbee Club - Women

Comment: select 
regexp_replace('Field Hockey, Ultimate Frisbee Club - Women, Ultimate Frisbee Club - Women','([^,]+)(,\1)+', '\1')

from dual returns Field Hockey, Ultimate Frisbee Club - Women seems to work.

Comment: \1 is the 1st matched term in round brackets  ([^,]+) - anything except a comma. so replace \1, \1 with \1 removing duplicates. do worry if you don't understand regexp is a black art.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  However, I found that the suggested pattern doesn't work with all cases I have, and I can't determine why.
For example, this doesn't work for me in Oracle 11R2:

SELECT regexp_replace('Baseball, Baseball, Basketball, Football, Ice Hockey', 
                      '([^,]+)(,\1)+', '\1')
  FROM DUAL;

But it does if I change the pattern to: '([^,]+)(, \1)+'
(Added a space after the second comma)

Comment: Hi this method relies on no spaces after the comma. So in your listarg have listagg(name, ',') not listagg(name, ', ') if the list is a hard coded use this to remove the spaces after a , and put spaces back after the , replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace('BBall, BBall, BBall, Football, Ice Hockey ',',\s*', ','),'([^,]+)(,\1)+', '\1'),',',', ') gives BBall, Football, Ice Hockey -solved!

Comment: Mike, it seems a lot cleaner to simply enhance the pattern to match than to have 3 layers of replace, no? I just pointed it out in case _others_ tried it.

Comment: your right haven't had time to do it yet..!

Comment: OZMIKE: My apologies for botching my example that didn't work.  It should have read: Ultimate Frisbee Club - Women, Field Hockey, Ultimate Frisbee Club - Women.

I just noticed your example above, where you're ordering by name, which would cause the regexp_replace to work as you proposed.

Thanks!

Comment: no worries - good to see your back..

Answer (score 5):

```
create table demotable(group_id number, name varchar2(100));
insert into demotable values(1,'David');
insert into demotable values(1,'John');
insert into demotable values(1,'Alan');
insert into demotable values(1,'David');
insert into demotable values(2,'Julie');
insert into demotable values(2,'Charles');
commit;

select group_id, 
       (select listagg(column_value, ',') within group (order by column_value) from table(coll_names)) as names
from (
  select group_id, collect(distinct name) as coll_names 
    from demotable
    group by group_id 
)

GROUP_ID    NAMES
1   Alan,David,John
2   Charles,Julie
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select group_id, 
       listagg(name, ',') within group (order by name) as names
       over (partition by group_id)   
from demotable
group by group_id
```

Answer (score 1):

below is undocumented and not recomended by oracle. 
and can not apply in function, show error

```
select wm_concat(distinct name) as names from demotable group by group_id
```

regards
zia

Comment: WM_concat will not work on oracle 12g by defalut, its a deprecated function. until 11g it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

I needed this peace of code as a subquery with some data filter before aggregation based on the outer most query but I wasn't able to do this using the chosen answer code because this filter should go in the inner most select (third level query) and the filter params was in the outer most select (first level query), which gave me the error **ORA-00904: "TB_OUTERMOST"."COL": invalid identifier** as the ANSI SQL states that table references (correlation names) are scoped to just one level deep.

I needed a solution with no levels of subquery and this one below worked great for me:

```
with

demotable as
(
  select 1 group_id, 'David'   name from dual union all
  select 1 group_id, 'John'    name from dual union all
  select 1 group_id, 'Alan'    name from dual union all
  select 1 group_id, 'David'   name from dual union all
  select 2 group_id, 'Julie'   name from dual union all
  select 2 group_id, 'Charlie' name from dual
)

select distinct 
  group_id, 
  listagg(name, ',') within group (order by name) over (partition by group_id) names
from demotable
-- where any filter I want
group by group_id, name
order by group_id;
```

Answer (score -2):

In 11g you can use the undocumented function wm_concat like this:

```
     select wm_concat(distinct name) as names from demotable group by group_id
```

Comment: Really, _don't_ use WM_CONCAT!  I have been bitten by changes in its behavior between different (minor!) versions of Oracle (11.2.0.1 vs. 11.2.0.2, when Oracle decided that WM_CONCAT should return a CLOB type)

Comment: yes returns a CLOB - not a string -FYI

Comment: just fyi ... no longer supported in 12c and newer.