# Eliminate duplicates using Oracle LISTAGG function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, analytics, oracle11gr2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LISTAGG in oracle to return distinct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510870/listagg-in-oracle-to-return-distinct-values)

I am using Oracle LISTAGG function but within my list of returned names I actually would like to eliminate duplicates and only return distinct values.

The query I have is something like this:

```
select a.id,
       a.change_id,
       LISTAGG(b.name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY b.name) AS "Product Name", 
from   table_a a,
       table_b b
where  a.id = 1
and    b.change_id = c.change_id
group by a.id, a.change_id
```

At the moment, it is returning (just showing one record):

```
1    1   NameA, NameA, NameB, NameC, NameD, Name D
```

What I would like returned is:

```
1    1   NameA, NameB, NameC, Name D
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [LISTAGG in oracle to return distinct values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510870/listagg-in-oracle-to-return-distinct-values) and also here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/696/eliminate-duplicates-in-listagg-oracle

Answer (score 1):

As the linked answers in the comment don't provide my flavor of solution, I'll post it anyway.

I'll only use `table_b` with dummy data to show the concept, you can easily add your join etc.:

```
with table_b as ( -- dummy data
 select 'name'||mod(level,3) name
        ,mod(level,3) id
   from dual
  connect by level < 10
 union all
 select 'name'||mod(level,2) name
        ,mod(level,3) id
   from dual
  connect by level < 10
)
select id
      ,RTRIM (
              XMLAGG (
                      XMLELEMENT (E,XMLATTRIBUTES (name|| ',' AS "Seg")
                      )
                     ORDER BY name ASC
              ).EXTRACT ('./E[not(@Seg = preceding-sibling::E/@Seg)]/@Seg'),
              ','
             ) AS "Product Name"
       ,LISTAGG(b.name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY b.name) AS "Product Name with dups"
  from table_b b
group by id;
```

(Idea taken from https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9634767&tstart=0#9943367)

Comment: That has to be quite slow, compared to a simple `LISTAGG` solution... Yet, I like it!

Comment: @LukasEder: yes, that might be slower, but `LISTAGG` has no `DISTINCT` and all other solutions do either two full table scans or use regexp which also is slower than `LISTAGG`. (And thanks for liking it)

Comment: I'm not sure if a full table scan is introduced merely because of applying `DISTINCT`? With `LISTAGG` (or any other aggregation method listing all elements within a group), there would be an unavoidable full table scan anyway, short of an index on the "listed" field... I could imagine that [`DISTINCT` in a subselect](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11511203/521799) works best, but that's just a guess

Comment: @LukasEder: correct, but I've not meant merely of `DISTINCT`. I thought of subselect with the need for multiple columns, but the answer [from your link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510870/listagg-in-oracle-to-return-distinct-values/11511203#11511203) provides a nice solution with row_number()