# LISTAGG Query "ORA-00937: not a single-group group function"

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a join with a list of comma separated values. For example:

```
rule_id | attribute_id
----------------------
1       | a
1       | b
2       | c
2       | d
```

should be:

```
rule_id | attribute_id
----------------------
1       | a,b
2       | c,d
```

I am attempting to do so using `LISTAGG`. However, with the below code, I'm getting `ORA-00937: not a single-group group function`. I noticed a `FOR PATH` syntax for sql-server, but it doesn't look like that works for our configuration. Here's my query:

```
SELECT r.rule_id as RULE_ID, 
LISTAGG(a.ATTRIBUTE_ID, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.ATTRIBUTE_ID) "ATTR_IDS"
FROM N_RULE r, N_ATTRIBUTE a 
WHERE r.RULE_ID = a.RULE_ID 
ORDER BY r.AUDIENCE, UPPER(r.NAME);
```

Comment: Add a `GROUP BY R.RULE_ID`. Why are you ordering by something that doesn't appear in your selected columns?

Comment: @ben It is not a duplicated question because it's asking the error when using `listagg`. The problem is related to using the partition clause of this function

Comment: The OP is trying to aggregate "attributes" over a "rule" @aturegano. Though the function can take a windowing clause this is not how the OP is using it according to their sample data and desired result. They also accepted an answer which says the same thing.

Comment: @ben You are right. Sorry for annoying you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think for your query to work, you need to add a `group by`, change the `order by`.  You should also use proper explicit join syntax:

```
SELECT r.rule_id as RULE_ID, 
       LISTAGG(a.ATTRIBUTE_ID, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.ATTRIBUTE_ID) as "ATTR_IDS"
FROM N_RULE r JOIN
     N_ATTRIBUTE a 
     ON r.RULE_ID = a.RULE_ID 
GROUP BY r.rule_id
ORDER BY r.rule_id;
```

Or, possibly you want to include other attribute in the results:

```
SELECT r.rule_id, r.AUDIENCE, UPPER(r.NAME) 
       LISTAGG(a.ATTRIBUTE_ID, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.ATTRIBUTE_ID) as "ATTR_IDS"
FROM N_RULE r JOIN
     N_ATTRIBUTE a 
     ON r.RULE_ID = a.RULE_ID 
GROUP BY r.rule_id, r.AUDIENCE, UPPER(r.NAME)
ORDER BY r.AUDIENCE, UPPER(r.NAME);
```

Comment: So it looks like in some rows, the comma separated values are the same (i.e. "54,54") Any thoughts on why?

Comment: That would mean that the `join` is returning duplicates.  This answer might give you ideas on how to fix it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510870/listagg-in-oracle-to-return-distinct-values.