# Concatenate two rows in the same column into one row (Oracle); use LISTAGG?

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation, listagg

I am using Oracle in Hyperion Studio.  I believe it is Oracle 11, but I am not sure how to check... this is all quite new to me, and I am very, very much a novice, I apologize.

In any case, I am using a query to return a list of classes along with the names of the instructors teaching them.

There are two issues that arise:

1. Instructor name is split up into multiple columns.  I solved this easily using recursive CONCAT in a Computed Item:

   ```
   CONCAT (Request.Instructor_Last_Name,CONCAT(', ',Request.Instructor_First_Name))
   ```
2. A course may have more than one instructor.  I want each course to only have one row in the results, so I figured I would try to show all instructors in a single concatenated field.

To try to solve the second problem, I attempted using LISTAGG and CONCAT together in a Computed Item:

```
LISTAGG(CONCAT (Request.Instructor_Last_Name,CONCAT(', ',Request.Instructor_First_Name)), 'and ') 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Request.Instructor_Last_Name DESC) "All Instructors"
```

This returns the error `ORA-00937: not a single-group group function`.

This brought me to this question: [LISTAGG Query "ORA-00937: not a single-group group function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24253262/listagg-query-ora-00937-not-a-single-group-group-function)
I tried variations on the solution there, with no success.  Here is one example I attempted:

```
LISTAGG(CONCAT (Request.Instructor_Last_Name,CONCAT(', ',Request.Instructor_First_Name)), 'and ') 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Request.Instructor_Last_Name DESC) "All Instructors"
FROM Request
GROUP BY *
```

This returns the error:

> ORA-00936: missing expression

I also tried replacing

```
LISTAGG(CONCAT (Request.Instructor_Last_Name,CONCAT(', ',Request.Instructor_First_Name)), 'and ')
```

with

```
LISTAGG(Request.Instructor_Last_Name || ', ' || Request.Instructor_First_Name,'and ')
```

based on something else I read, but that didn't seem to make any difference (I'm not even sure if that would work anyway).

This has exhausted me.  I'm sure at this point the answer must be eluding me only due to my inexperience, so any help is hugely appreciated...

---

Here is a very stripped-down version of the query, using the code vkp suggested (these are Banner tables, as some may recognize):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
AL1.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE, AL1.SFRSTCR_CRN, 
AL3.SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME, AL3.SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME, 
CONCAT ((AL3.SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME),CONCAT(', ',(AL3.SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME))),   
select Student_Registration_CRN,
LISTAGG((Instructor_Last_Name||', '||Instructor_First_Name), 'and '))
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Instructor_Last_Name DESC) "All Instructors"
FROM Request
group by Student_Registration_CRN 
FROM SATURN.SFRSTCR AL1, SATURN.SIRASGN AL2, SATURN.SPRIDEN AL3 
WHERE ( AL1.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = AL2.SIRASGN_TERM_CODE (+) 
AND  AL1.SFRSTCR_CRN = AL2.SIRASGN_CRN (+) 
AND  AL2.SIRASGN_PIDM = AL3.SPRIDEN_PIDM (+))  
AND ((AL3.SPRIDEN_CHANGE_IND IS NULL AND AL1.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE='201660'))
```

This produces the error:

> ORA-00936: missing expression

I have used aliases for some of the column names, so I tried the suggested code without aliases, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

---

I have tried using Boneist's suggested SQL, by importing the .SQL file directly, rather than using the visual builder and Computed Items.  Here is what I tried to run:

```
select distinct
   al1.sfrstcr_term_code,
   al1.sfrstcr_crn,
   al3.spriden_first_name,
   al3.spriden_last_name,
   al3.spriden_last_name||', '||al3.spriden_first_name,
   (select   sfrstcr_crn,
             listagg(spriden_last_name || ', ' || spriden_first_name, 'and ')
               within group (order by spriden_last_name desc)
    from     request req
    where    sfrstcr_crn = al1.sfrstcr_crn
    group by sfrstcr_crn) "All Instructors"
from   saturn.sfrstcr al1
   left outer join saturn.sirasgn al2 on (al1.sfrstcr_term_code = al2.sirasgn_term_code
                                          and al1.sfrstcr_crn = al2.sirasgn_crn)
   left outer join saturn.spriden al3 on (al2.sirasgn_pidm = al3.spriden_pidm(+))
where  al3.spriden_change_ind is null
and    al1.sfrstcr_term_code = '201660';
```

Unfortunately, this returns the error:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

I thought, based on some searching, that it might somehow be that the quotes were not importing correctly, so I tried something even more basic:

```
select distinct
   al1.sfrstcr_term_code,
   al1.sfrstcr_crn,
   al3.spriden_first_name,
   al3.spriden_last_name
from   saturn.sfrstcr al1
   left outer join saturn.sirasgn al2 on (al1.sfrstcr_term_code = al2.sirasgn_term_code
                                          and al1.sfrstcr_crn = al2.sirasgn_crn)
   left outer join saturn.spriden al3 on (al2.sirasgn_pidm = al3.spriden_pidm(+))
where  al3.spriden_change_ind is null;
```

But I still get the same error...   I tried searching for what else could cause it, but didn't find anything helpful... I am not sure what else to try at this point.

Comment: `group by *`? what is this supposed to do?

Comment: I read somewhere in my searching that you have to group by what was being selected, and I wasn't sure what exactly a Computed Item selects, so I thought I would try just grouping by anything... which didn't seem to work, oops...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like perhaps the CONCAT is unnecessary?

http://nimishgarg.blogspot.in/2010/02/oracle-new-string-aggregation.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select class_id,
LISTAGG((Instructor_Last_Name||', '||Instructor_First_Name), 'and '))
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Instructor_Last_Name DESC) "All Instructors"
FROM Request
group by class_id
```

Comment: Replacing class_id with the appropriate column name (it's Student_Registration_CRN, sorry to have omitted it!), I tried this but unfortunately received the error `ORA-00936: missing expression`...

Comment: can you post the full query being used?

Comment: Sure... it's a bit complicated, as it references several tables, but I'll add it above...

Comment: I just added a stripped-down version above.  I must step away for a while so apologies if I do not respond promptly!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after something along the lines of:

```
with sample_data as (select 'Bob' first_name, 'Jones' last_name, 1 course_id from dual union all
                     select 'John' first_name, 'Bloggs' last_name, 1 course_id from dual union all
                     select 'Fred' first_name, 'Hoskins' last_name, 1 course_id from dual union all
                     select 'Bob' first_name, 'Jones' last_name, 2 course_id from dual union all
                     select 'John' first_name, 'Bloggs' last_name, 2 course_id from dual union all
                     select 'Fred' first_name, 'Hoskins' last_name, 3 course_id from dual)
-- end of setting up a subquery to mimic a table called sample_data for use in the SQL below:
select course_id,
       listagg(first_name||' '||last_name, ', ') within group (order by last_name) instructors
from   sample_data
group by course_id;


 COURSE_ID INSTRUCTORS                             
---------- ----------------------------------------
         1 John Bloggs, Fred Hoskins, Bob Jones    
         2 John Bloggs, Bob Jones                  
         3 Fred Hoskins
```

Note how I've replaced your `CONCAT`s with `||`, as that is much more flexible and doesn't require nesting of `CONCAT`s if you're joining more than two strings together! It's also much easier to read.

---

I suspect that the query you're looking for is something along the lines of:

```
select distinct
       al1.sfrstcr_term_code,
       al1.sfrstcr_crn,
       al3.spriden_first_name,
       al3.spriden_last_name,
       al3.spriden_last_name||', '||al3.spriden_first_name,
       (select   student_registration_crn,
                 listagg(instructor_last_name || ', ' || instructor_first_name, 'and ')
                   within group (order by instructor_last_name desc)
        from     request req
        where    <join condition(s) between this query and the main query>
        group by student_registration_crn) "All Instructors"
from   saturn.sfrstcr al1
       left outer join saturn.sirasgn al2 on (al1.sfrstcr_term_code = al2.sirasgn_term_code
                                              and al1.sfrstcr_crn = al2.sirasgn_crn)
       left outer join saturn.spriden al3 on (al2.sirasgn_pidm = al3.spriden_pidm(+))
where  al3.spriden_change_ind is null
and    al1.sfrstcr_term_code = '201660';
```

There were some issues with your query that I have corrected:

1. The scalar subquery (that's when you populate a column using a select statement) needs to be enclosed in brackets.
2. Where possible, use the newer ANSI-style joins, rather than the old style joins.
3. You're missing a join condition from your scalar subquery to your outer query - you'll need to include those. Also, a scalar subquery needs to return at most one row, otherwise you'll get an error.

Comment: As with vkp's answer, I tried this, replacing the appropriate field names, but received the error `ORA-00936: missing expression`.  I am putting this code in as a Computed Item.  Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: @Violet I've updated my answer with some pointers about your stripped down query. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you!  The SQL (aside from the subquery) was all auto-generated by Hyperion Studio, but I just discovered that it is possible to import custom SQL, so I tried doing so.  I have appended my results to my original question.