# How to select distinct values while using multiple LISTAGG() function in select clause?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to retrieve race_code,chara_code and reason_code as a list using following query:

```
SELECT a.pid,
       LISTAGG(a.rc, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.rc) AS race,
       LISTAGG(a.cc, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.cc) as chara_codes,
       LISTAGG(a.rrc, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.rrc) AS removal_reason
FROM (
   SELECT UNIQUE
          p.person_id pid,
          r.race_code rc,
          c.characteristic_code cc,
          rr.removal_reason_code rrc
     FROM person p left outer join race r on p.person_id = r.person_id
          left outer join characteristic c on p.person_id = c.person_id
          left outer join placement_episode pe on p.person_id = pe.child_id
          left outer join removal_reason rr on pe.placement_episode_id = rr.placement_episode_id
     ) a
GROUP BY a.pid
```

I tried this query after referencing some links like [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510870/listagg-in-oracle-to-return-distinct-values) and [link2](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques). But after doing this also I am not able to get unique values for all fields.

My o/p is coming like:

```
pid      race_code     chara_code      reason_code
 1        a,b,b,c     c1,c1,c2,c3     r1,r2,r3,r3
 2       a,c,d,d,d      c1,c2,c2        r3,r3

and so on.
```

If I try to retrieve only one one field at a time with keeping required join opeartions then it's giving correct result. But for multiple LISTAGG() functions its repeating values.
I am not getting  a way to do this. Is there any other way in which I can get distinct values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is unfortunately more complicated than it needs to be.  But, you can do it.  The idea is to enumerate each of the values, and then use `case` to pass a `NULL` argument to `LISTAGG()`.

```
SELECT a.pid,
       LISTAGG(CASE WHEN rc_seqnum = 1 THEN a.rc END, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.rc) AS race,
       LISTAGG(CASE WHEN cc_seqnum = 1 THEN a.cc END, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.cc) as chara_codes,
       LISTAGG(CASE WHEN rrc_seqnum = 1 THEN a.rrc END, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.rrc) AS removal_reason
FROM (SELECT p.person_id as pid, r.race_code as rc, c.characteristic_code as cc,
              rr.removal_reason_code as rrc,
             row_number() over (partition by p.person_id, r.race_code order by r.race_code) as rc_seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by p.person_id, c.characteristic_code order by c.characteristic_code) as cc_seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by p.person_id, rr.removal_reason_code order by rr.removal_reason_code) as rrc_seqnum
      FROM person p left outer join race r on p.person_id = r.person_id
           left outer join characteristic c on p.person_id = c.person_id
           left outer join placement_episode pe on p.person_id = pe.child_id
           left outer join removal_reason rr on pe.placement_episode_id = rr.placement_episode_id
     ) a
GROUP BY a.pid;
```

The query is enumerating the rows based on each person and field combination.  The first time the value is seen, it gets a value of "1", subsequent values increase incrementally.  The `LISTAGG()` only chooses the first value.

You should learn about analytic functions.  They are very useful.

Comment: Thanks for your response. There is additional ')' in second line of your query. Please remove it. Its throwing error. And can you please give some more explanation or some links for logic that you used? I am not aware about partition concept that you used. And this query works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use scalar sub queries as in this example:

```
select p.person_id
     , (select LISTAGG(rc, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rc) 
          from race r where r.person_id = p.person_id
         group by r.person_id) race
     , (select LISTAGG(cc, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cc) 
          from characteristic r where r.person_id = p.person_id
         group by r.person_id) chara_codes
     , (select LISTAGG(rrc, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rrc) 
          from removal_reason r where r.person_id = p.person_id
         group by r.person_id) removal_reason
  from person p;
```

Or you can precompute the lists as in this example:

```
with race_list as (
  select person_id
       , LISTAGG(rc, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rc) race
    from race
   group by person_id
), characteristic_list as (
  select person_id
       , LISTAGG(cc, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cc) chara_codes
    from characteristic
   group by person_id
), removal_reason_list as (
  select person_id
       , LISTAGG(rrc, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rrc) removal_reason
    from removal_reason
   group by person_id
)
select p.person_id
     , r.race
     , c.chara_codes
     , rr.removal_reason
  from person p
  join race_list r
    on r.person_id = p.person_id
  join characteristic_list c
    on c.person_id = p.person_id
  join removal_reason_list rr
    on rr.person_id = p.person_id;
```