# Oracle - unique Listagg values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, listagg

I am new to using Listagg. The following script works in respect of it gives me a list of values but, the list duplicates the values.

Is it possible to use Listagg to return only a unique list of values.

I am using oracle 10g.

```
select distinct ds.catnr,ds.planqty, ds.ordnr, ds.posnr, ds.segnr, 
listagg(case when not li.paco is null then (select unique max(li1.paco) from leos_item li1 where li.av_part_no = li1.av_part_no) end, ', ') within group (order by pd.part_no) inq_no
from oes_delsegview ds, oes_address ad, oes_opos op, oes_nrbom nr, scm_prodtyp sp, leos_item li, part_description pd
where ds.delnr = ad.key
and ad.adr = ds.deladr
and ds.pos_o_status not in ('9', 'D')
and ds.pos_c_status not in ('9', 'D')
and ds.seg_o_status not in ('9', 'D')
and ds.seg_c_status not in ('9', 'D')
and ds.cunr in ('W31170','W31172')
and ds.pos_type != 'RC'
and ds.ordnr = op.ordnr
and ds.posnr = op.posnr
and ds.catnr = pd.catnr
and ds.prodtyp = pd.prodtyp
and ds.packtyp = pd.packtyp
and ds.catnr = nr.p_catnr (+)
and ds.prodtyp = nr.p_prodtyp (+)
and ds.packtyp = nr.p_packtyp (+)
and nr.c_prodtyp = sp.prodtyp (+) 
and sp.prodgrp (+) = 'COMP'
and substr(nr.c_prodtyp,1,2) not in ('MT','LF')
and nr.c_catnr = li.catnr (+)
and nr.c_prodtyp = li.prodtyp (+)
and nr.c_packtyp = li.packtyp (+)
and pd.catnr = '9780007938797'
group by ds.catnr,ds.planqty, ds.ordnr, ds.posnr, ds.segnr
```

The result of my Listagg is:

```
14/061127-12, 14/061127-16, 14/061127-16, 14/061127-16, 14/061127-16, 14/061127-16, 14/061127-16, 14/061127-16, 14/061127-16, 14/061127-16, 14/061127-16, 14/061127-16, 14/061127-16, 14/061127-16, 14/061127-16, 14/061127-16, 14/061127-16, 14/061127-16, 14/061127-16, 14/061127-16, 14/061127-16
```

What I would like to see is:

```
14/061127-12, 14/061127-16
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LISTAGG in oracle to return distinct values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510870/listagg-in-oracle-to-return-distinct-values)

Answer (score 2):

I removed the first `distinct` since your already `group by` all fields in your `Select` query, and replaced the `case when` with a `select` query:

```
select ds.catnr,ds.planqty, ds.ordnr, ds.posnr, ds.segnr, 
    listagg((select distinct max(li1.paco) from leos_item li1 where li.av_part_no = li1.av_part_no and li.paco is not null), ', ') within group (order by pd.part_no) inq_no
    from oes_delsegview ds, oes_address ad, oes_opos op, oes_nrbom nr, scm_prodtyp sp, leos_item li, part_description pd
    where ds.delnr = ad.key
    and ad.adr = ds.deladr
    and ds.pos_o_status not in ('9', 'D')
    and ds.pos_c_status not in ('9', 'D')
    and ds.seg_o_status not in ('9', 'D')
    and ds.seg_c_status not in ('9', 'D')
    and ds.cunr in ('W31170','W31172')
    and ds.pos_type != 'RC'
    and ds.ordnr = op.ordnr
    and ds.posnr = op.posnr
    and ds.catnr = pd.catnr
    and ds.prodtyp = pd.prodtyp
    and ds.packtyp = pd.packtyp
    and ds.catnr = nr.p_catnr (+)
    and ds.prodtyp = nr.p_prodtyp (+)
    and ds.packtyp = nr.p_packtyp (+)
    and nr.c_prodtyp = sp.prodtyp (+) 
    and sp.prodgrp (+) = 'COMP'
    and substr(nr.c_prodtyp,1,2) not in ('MT','LF')
    and nr.c_catnr = li.catnr (+)
    and nr.c_prodtyp = li.prodtyp (+)
    and nr.c_packtyp = li.packtyp (+)
    and pd.catnr = '9780007938797'
    group by ds.catnr,ds.planqty, ds.ordnr, ds.posnr, ds.segnr
```

Comment: Hi haytem, thank you but, I still have the same result (a list of duplicate values).

Answer (score 0):

I used a regexp_replace function to remove duplicates in my listagg;

```
regexp_replace(
    listagg((select distinct max(li1.paco) from leos_item li1 where li.av_part_no = li1.av_part_no and li.paco is not null), ', ') within group (order by pd.part_no) 
    ,'([^,]+)(,\1)+', '\1') inq_no
```

Appears to work OK.

[LISTAGG in oracle to return distinct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510870/listagg-in-oracle-to-return-distinct-values)

Comment: This regex replacement has a bug. Try `reviews,search`: replaced with 'reviewsearch'. I'll post the fixed one as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via RegEx replacement. Here is an example:

```
-- Citations Per Year - Cited Publications main query. Includes list of unique associated core project numbers, ordered by core project number.
SELECT ptc.pmid AS pmid, ptc.pmc_id, ptc.pub_title AS pubtitle, ptc.author_list AS authorlist,
  ptc.pub_date AS pubdate,
  REGEXP_REPLACE( LISTAGG ( ppcc.admin_phs_org_code || 
    TO_CHAR(ppcc.serial_num,'FM000000'), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ppcc.admin_phs_org_code || 
    TO_CHAR(ppcc.serial_num,'FM000000')),
    '(^|,)(.+)(,\2)+', '\1\2')
  AS projectNum
FROM publication_total_citations ptc
  JOIN proj_paper_citation_counts ppcc
    ON ptc.pmid = ppcc.pmid
   AND ppcc.citation_year = 2013
  JOIN user_appls ua
    ON ppcc.admin_phs_org_code = ua.admin_phs_org_code
   AND ppcc.serial_num = ua.serial_num
   AND ua.login_id = 'EVANSF'
GROUP BY ptc.pmid, ptc.pmc_id, ptc.pub_title, ptc.author_list, ptc.pub_date
ORDER BY pmid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Super simple answer solved

```
select
regexp_replace('14/061127-12, 14/061127-16, 14/061127-16','([^,]+)(,\1)*(,|$)', '\1\3')


from dual
```

->

14/061127-12, 14/061127-16

see my full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510870/listagg-in-oracle-to-return-distinct-values/22624072#22624072)

Comment: Does not work unless the string is first sorted.  Or rather, all duplicates have to be next to each other in the list in order for this regex to work.

Comment: see my full answer  in link above