# How to Use COLLECT with VARCHAR2 Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle10g, collect, listagg

I'm trying to get the COLLECT function to work for me.  I'm using 10g and therefore found that LISTAGG and WM_CONCAT will not work (invalid identifier errors). The data I have is for example as follows.

```
Order  Lot
123    A23088
123    A23089
089    AABBCC
305    120848
305    CCDDYY
```

What I need returned is as follows

```
Order   Lot
123     A23088, A23089
089     AABBCC
305     120848, CCDDYY
```

Using the following, I get the error: TO_STRING is an invalid identifier

```
TO_STRING ( CAST(COLLECT(DISTINCT LOT) AS varchar2(100)) ) AS LOT
```

Using the following, I get the error: expected CHAR "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

```
TO_CHAR ( CAST(COLLECT(DISTINCT LOT) AS varchar2(100)) ) AS LOT
```

Using the following, I get the error: expected NUMBER "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

```
COLLECT(DISTINCT WHSE_LOT)
```

Is there any way to get this function to work for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [collect function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions031.htm#SQLRF06304) creates a nested table, in your case a table of strings, which you would then cast to a specific type - that is, a type defined as a table of varchar2. You can't cast to a single string.

There are some well-known lists of string aggregation techniques, [like this one](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques). There is one [that uses collect](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques#collect), but you still need the table type and a function to convert the generated table to a delimited string.

Copying that example verbatim:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_varchar2_tab AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tab_to_string (p_varchar2_tab  IN  t_varchar2_tab,
                                          p_delimiter     IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ',') RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  l_string     VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN p_varchar2_tab.FIRST .. p_varchar2_tab.LAST LOOP
    IF i != p_varchar2_tab.FIRST THEN
      l_string := l_string || p_delimiter;
    END IF;
    l_string := l_string || p_varchar2_tab(i);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN l_string;
END tab_to_string;
/
```

With that type and function you then do:

```
SELECT tab_to_string(CAST(COLLECT(DISTINCT lot) AS t_varchar2_tab)) AS lot FROM ...
```

---

Interestingly, [the 10g version of collect](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions024.htm) doesn't support `DISTINCT`; it doesn't complain (!?), but leaves duplicates.

You can pass the collection through [the set function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions144.htm) to remove the duplicates:

```
SELECT tab_to_string(SET(CAST(COLLECT(DISTINCT lot) AS t_varchar2_tab))) AS lot FROM ...
```

Quick demo run in 10.2.0.5:

```
create table table1(order_no number, lot varchar2(10));

insert into table1 values (590288, '2016538');
insert into table1 values (590288, '2016535');
insert into table1 values (590288, '6016535');
insert into table1 values (590288, '2016535');
insert into table1 values (590288, '2016538');

SELECT order_no, tab_to_string(SET(CAST(COLLECT(DISTINCT lot) AS t_varchar2_tab))) AS LOT
FROM table1 WHERE order_no = 590288 GROUP BY order_no;

  ORDER_NO LOT                                              
---------- --------------------------------------------------
    590288 2016538,2016535,6016535
```

Comment: Thank you for the help @AlexPoole.  I found this solution to work with one exception - not just distinct values are returned.  For example,          `SELECT order_no, tab_to_string(CAST(COLLECT(DISTINCT lot) AS t_varchar2_tab)) AS LOT FROM table1 WHERE order_no = 590288 GROUP BY order_no;`         Returns                                                                                                       Order_No   Lot                                                                                      590288       2016535,2016535,6016535,2016538,2016538                 Any Suggestions?

Comment: @ESC - updated to pass the collection through `SET()` to remove the suplicates, since 10g doesn't recognise `COLLECT(DISTINCT ...)`.

Comment: @AlexPoole, if I want to apply COLLECT on multiple columns? Say Lot1, Lot2..then how to write function `tab_to_string`?
`CAST(COLLECT(lot1 || ':' || lot2) AS t_varchar2_tab) AS lotagg`  works. But when `tab_to_string` function is applied, it gives error.