# Remove duplicates from listagg

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a listagg command in my query and I want to eliminate the duplicates by using REGEXP_REPLACE in a cell. I am totaly novice with regex.
What pattern should I use in order to achieve that?

For example In my row I have these values (the values may be differenct in other rows):

```
25%, 25%, 25%, 25%, 25%, 25%, 25%, 25%, 25%
```

Comment: `regex` is not the most appropriate tool for this task (if can be used at all).

Comment: Why aren't you eliminating duplicates *before* aggregating them?

Comment: Remove duplicates by row?

Comment: @AlexPoole How can I do that? These values are being returned in a cell with listagg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LISTAGG in oracle to return distinct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510870/listagg-in-oracle-to-return-distinct-values)

Answer (score 1):

You could remove duplicates within your sql query using a subquery or a cte to collect your data:

```
select listagg(col1, ',') within group (order by col1) 
from 
(select distinct col1 from mytable) data
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fe3bb/8/0