# How I remove duplicates from listagg

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my code:

```
SELECT rule,
       DATASET,
       type,
       LISTAGG(source,';') within GROUP (ORDER BY source) AS source,
       TARGET, 
       LISTAGG(filter,';') within GROUP (ORDER BY filter)  AS filter
FROM demo_table;
```

My problem is with the two `listagg()` that I have used. In case of two sources and one filter it is giving duplicate filter and vice versa. What can I add to have only exact number of source and filter?

Comment: Can you provide sample data? i.e sqlfiddle

Comment: Duplicate of [LISTAGG in oracle to return distinct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510870/listagg-in-oracle-to-return-distinct-values)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First select DISTINCT values you need, then apply LISTAGG to them. Here's an example based on Scott's schema.

```
SQL> -- Duplicate jobs within the department
SQL> select deptno, listagg(job, ', ') within group (order by job) jobs
  2  from emp
  3  group by deptno;

    DEPTNO JOBS
---------- ------------------------------------------------------------
        10 CLERK, MANAGER, PRESIDENT
        20 ANALYST, ANALYST, CLERK, CLERK, MANAGER
        30 CLERK, MANAGER, SALESMAN, SALESMAN, SALESMAN, SALESMAN

SQL>
SQL> -- This won't work - DISTINCT can't be used in LISTAGG
SQL> select deptno, listagg(distinct job, ', ') within group (order by job) jobs
  2  from emp
  3  group by deptno;
select deptno, listagg(distinct job, ', ') within group (order by job) jobs
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-30482: DISTINCT option not allowed for this function


SQL>
SQL> -- So - select distinct jobs first, then apply LISTAGG to it
SQL> select x.deptno, listagg(x.job, ', ') within group (order by x.job) jobs
  2  from (select distinct deptno, job
  3        from emp) x
  4  group by x.deptno;

    DEPTNO JOBS
---------- ------------------------------------------------------------
        10 CLERK, MANAGER, PRESIDENT
        20 ANALYST, CLERK, MANAGER
        30 CLERK, MANAGER, SALESMAN

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Distinct inside LISTAGG()

```
SELECT rule, 
       DATASET, 
       type, 
       LISTAGG(DISTINCT source,';') within GROUP ( ORDER BY source) AS source,
       TARGET, 
       LISTAGG(DISTINCT filter,';') within GROUP ( ORDER BY filter) AS filter 
FROM demo_table;
```

Comment: I tried but it says ORA-30482: DISTINCT option not allowed for this function
30482. 00000 -  "DISTINCT option not allowed for this function"

Comment: because it works only for Oracle 19c. for versions comparison regarding `listagg` see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11511203/5036360