# oracle distinct with listagg

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct, listagg

I have a table. I can show all the data of a colomn in my table using ',' in the same line. but I can't apply it distinctly. hepl please

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask section "Help others reproduce the problem".. iam voteclosing this question to be unclear.

Comment: It's a shame they missed the `DISTINCT` option when they introduced `LISTAGG`. This has often been complained about. Finally Oracle has reacted: `LISTAGG` will feature `DISTINCT` as of version 19c. See here: https://community.oracle.com/ideas/12533

Comment: There is a trick to use `regexp_replace` on the `listagg` result to remove duplicates. You can google it and it's also mentioned in the link above. However, the `listagg` string can get very big before you can interfere and result in an exception. I must admit I often use `wm_concat` when I want distinct lists.

Comment: [See this too.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11510870/266304)

Answer (score 3):

This is tricky.  One simple suggestion is to use `select distinct`:

```
select listagg(col, ',') within group (order by col)
from (select distinct col from t) x;
```

However, that makes it difficult to calculate other aggregations (or to generate more than on `listagg()` result).  Another way is to use window functions in combination with `listagg()`:

```
select listagg(case when seqnum = 1 then col end, ',') within group (order by col)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col order by col) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
```