# How is empty string and space treated in regular expression?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I was trying to concatenate distinct values of rows using LISTAGG and REGEXP_REPLACE functions as described in this link:
[LISTAGG in Oracle to return distinct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510870/listagg-in-oracle-to-return-distinct-values).

I am trying to understand what is going on, I made some changes and started playing with it. However, I wasn't getting the answer I was expecting. It seems like I'm missing some key concept on how "empty string" and "space" are treated by the regexp engine. How does the regexp engine process the why_space_affected_here, why_space_affected_here, why_space_not_affected_here, matching_empty_string, and why_space_not_affected columns in the below sample query?

```
select group_key
     , listagg(id, ', ') within group (order by id) as listagg_output`
     , regexp_replace(listagg(id, ', ') within group (order by id), '([^,]*)(, \1)+', '\1') as why_space_affected_here
     , regexp_replace(listagg(id, ', ') within group (order by id), '([^,]*)(,\1)+', '\1') as why_space_not_affected_here
     , regexp_replace(listagg(id, ', ') within group (order by id), '([^,]*)(, \1)+', 'T') as matching_empty_string
     , regexp_replace(listagg(id, ', ') within group (order by id), '([^,]*)(, \1)+($|,)', '\1\3') as why_space_not_affected
from (
    select 22 group_key, 1 id from dual
    union all
    select 22 group_key, 2 id from dual
    union all
    select 22 group_key,  3 id from dual
    union all
    select 22 group_key, 3 id from dual
    )
group by group_key;
```

I was expecting the spaces to be reserved for the why_space_affected_here column (the query given below):
`regexp_replace(listagg(id, ', ') within group (order by id), '([^,]*)(, \1)+', '\1') as why_space_affected_here`.

Comment: Add sample data. Add expected output. Try to shorten your query.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( '1, 2, 3, 3', '([^,]*)(, \1)+', '\1') as why_space_affected_here
FROM DUAL
```

Outputs `123` because the first and second replacements `([^,]*)` matches a zero-width string and only the comma and space are replaced with a zero-width string and then in the third replacement `([^,]*)` matches `3` and `3, 3` is replace by just `3`.

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( '1, 2, 3, 3', '([^,]*)(,\1)+', '\1') as why_space_not_affected_here
FROM DUAL
```

Outputs `1 2 3` as the first and second replacements `([^,]*)` matches a zero-width string and only the commas are replaced and the third replacement `([^,]*)` matches space then 3 and the `, 3` is removed.

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( '1, 2, 3, 3', '([^,]*)(, \1)+', 'T') as matching_empty_string
FROM DUAL
```

Outputs `1T2TT` - this is exactly the same as your first example but instead of keeping the first capture group you're replacing everything with `T`.

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( '1, 2, 3, 3', '([^,]*)(, \1)+($|,)', '\1\3') as why_space_not_affected
FROM DUAL
```

Outputs `1, 2, 3` as its first match is to `3, 3` when `([^,]*)` matches `3` and `($|,)` matches the end of the string.

---

> Can you please describe or walk me through how the first and second replacements matches a zero-width string?

For the regular expression `([^,]*)(, \1)+` then `[^,]` matches a non-comma chatacter. `[^,]*` matches zero-or-more non-comma characters.

- From the start of the string:

  ```
  1, 2, 3, 3
  ^^^^
  ```

  `([^,]*)` could match `1` but it is succeeded by `, 2` and not by `, 1` so this will not match the entire pattern.
- Still at the start of the string:

  ```
  1, 2, 3, 3
  ^
  ```

  `([^,]*)` could match a zero-width (empty) sub-string but the next character is a `1` and not a `,` so this will not match the entire pattern and having tried all possibile matches the pattern matcher will move on to testing starting from the next character.
- Moving on the starting from the next character:

  ```
  1, 2, 3, 3
   ^^
  ```

  `([^,]*)` cannot match the comma but it can match a zero-width (empty) string which is succeeded by comma then space and then a repeat of the first match, a zero-width sub-string. So the pattern will successfully match just a comma and a space.
- Starting from `2` we effectively repeat the previous steps and end up skipping the `2` character and matching a zero-width sub-string then comma then space then the repeated zero-width sub-string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @MT0! I get how the third replacement `([^,]*)` matches 3 and 3, 3 is replace by just 3. What I'm not getting is how  the first and second replacements `([^,]*)` matches a zero-width string and only the comma and space are replaced with a zero-width string in the below query:                                `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( '1, 2, 3, 3', '([^,]*)(, \1)+', 'T') as matching_empty_string
FROM DUAL`.  Can you please describe or walk me through how the first and second replacements matches a zero-width string? Sorry, this is a little foreign to me.