# PL/SQL finding and let row wise duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, distinct, oracle18c

I have a table with 10 columns. Looks like this

```
NULL 1 1 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 2 NULL
1 NULL NULL 2 NULL 1 NULL NULL 2 NULL
NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 2 NULL
```

I need a SQL Query that returns this: (distinct row-wise)

```
1 2
1 2
NULL
2
```

Comment: What version of Oracle?

Comment: I dont understand whats the logic of above output some rows include nulls some not and that is not row vise distinct but column vise

Comment: @GordonLinoff 18c

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja I want per row all distinct values except the NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `UNPIVOT` the columns to rows (and keep the `NULL` values) and then filter to keep `DISTINCT` rows and then aggregate the rows into a string ignoring the `NULL` values unless they're all `NULL`:

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG( value, ' ' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY value ) AS vals
FROM   (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         rn,
         value,
         COUNT(value) OVER ( PARTITION BY rn ) AS num_values
  FROM   (
    SELECT ROWNUM AS rn,
           t.*
    FROM   table_name t
  )
  UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS (
    value FOR key IN ( col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10 )
  )
)
WHERE num_values = 0
OR    value IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY rn
```

So, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  col1 NUMBER,
  col2 NUMBER,
  col3 NUMBER,
  col4 NUMBER,
  col5 NUMBER,
  col6 NUMBER,
  col7 NUMBER,
  col8 NUMBER,
  col9 NUMBER,
  col10 NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO table_name
SELECT NULL,    1,    1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,    2, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT    1, NULL, NULL,    2, NULL,    1, NULL, NULL,    2, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,    2, NULL FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> | VALS |
> | :--- |
> | 1 2  |
> | 1 2  |
> | null |
> | 2    |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d69db91ae7ea328ae22941e6d1395d59)*

Comment: How come your logic is different to mine?

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja You are trying to use `LISTAGG( DISTINCT ... )` which is syntactically invalid on Oracle 18c; I have a sub-query to perform the `DISTINCT` filtering before using `LISTAGG` and also have additional filtering to keep the `NULL` value when all the columns are `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `hiearchy query` as follows:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(E, ' ') WITHIN GROUP( ORDER BY E )
FROM
    ( SELECT DISTINCT
            ROWID AS RID,
            DECODE(COLUMN_VALUE, 1, COL1, 2, COL2, 3, COL3, 4, COL4 ..., 10, COL10) AS E
        FROM YOUR_TABLE
             CROSS JOIN TABLE ( CAST(MULTISET(
                SELECT LEVEL
                  FROM DUAL
                CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10 ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST) )
    )
GROUP BY RID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below if that helps trying to unpivot the columns into 1 eliminating nulls keeping the rowid mantained for each previous selection before unpivoting then aggregating via grouping

```
    Select op from (Select rn, 
     listagg(distinct col, 
       ',') within group (order by 
         col) as  op from
   (  Select *, row_number() over(
    Partition by col1, col2.. Col10 order by
   ..) rn
     from table
    UnPIVOT 
  (COL, num) IN   ( (COL1, COL2,... 
     Col10), rn)) 

   ) where col is not null group by 
  rn)
```

Comment: `LISTAGG` does not support the `DISTINCT` keyword.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510870/listagg-in-oracle-to-return-distinct-values check this for newer version

Comment: The OP is using Oracle 18c - `LISTAGG( DISTINCT ... )` is not supported.