# Oracle: Generate WHERE clause from resultset ids?

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause, toad, maximo

*In Toad for Oracle 12:*

I've selected rows from a table using a complex query.

I want to select those same rows in the system's [application's WHERE clause](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/control-desk/7.6.0?topic=SSWT9A_7.6.0/com.ibm.mbs.doc/gp_ui/c_SQL_search.html?cp=SSWT9A_7.6.0).

However, the application doesn't support full SELECT statements, only WHERE clauses. And occasionally, it doesn't allow  complex queries as subqueries in the WHERE clause, which is the case for my current query.

---

As an alternative, is there a way to get  Toad to **generate a WHERE clause from the resultset's IDs?**

I would copy/paste the WHERE clause into the application. This is a common task, so it would be nice if there was something easy like a button in Toad that would do this.

---

Example:

Use the resultset...

```
ID    VAL
 1      A
 2      B
 3      C
```

...to generate a WHERE clause:

```
where id in (1,2,3)
```

Or if the IDs are text:

```
where id in ('1','2','3')
```

Comment: Where does the `3` comes from?

Comment: Just copy your output and replace newlines with comma (or `','` depending on the datatype).

Comment: PL/SQL Developer can do this - highlight the column in the results grid, right-click, "Copy as Expression List". Does Toad have something similar if you right-click on the results grid column? (I don't see anything in SQL Developer  20.2 but perhaps I am missing something.)

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I haven't found an equivalent tool in Toad yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply [`listagg`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) function to your output and concatenate output IDs to list:

```
with a as (
  <your_current_query>
)
select 'where id in ('
  || listagg(id, ',') within group(order by id)
  || ')' as where_clause
from a
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery in the `where` clause:

```
where id in (select id
             from . . .  -- your complicated query here
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Maximo-specific version of @astentx's query:

```
with a as (

<<your query>>

)
select 'wonum in ('''
  || listagg(wonum, ''', ''') within group(order by wonum)
  || ''')' as where_clause
from a
```

---

And this query uses the syntax for Maximo's filtering fields:

```
with a as (

<<your query>>
    
    )
select '='
  || listagg(attributename, ', =') within group(order by attributename)
  || '' as where_clause
from a
```

[image]

---

Related:

- [LISTAGG in Oracle to return distinct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510870/listagg-in-oracle-to-return-distinct-values)
- [SQL Server: Generate WHERE clause from resultset ids?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70106386/sql-server-generate-where-clause-from-resultset-ids/70106653#70106653)