# SQL Server: Generate WHERE clause from resultset ids?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, listagg

I have a query that produces the following resultset:

```
ID (text)    VAL
 1           A
 2           B
 3           C
```

I want to generate a WHERE clause from the resultset IDs:

```
where id in ('1','2','3')
```

---

With  Oracle, I can use the following query to generate a WHERE clause:

```
with a as (

  <my_query>

)
select 'where id in ('
  || listagg(id, ',') within group(order by id)
  || ')' as where_clause
from a
```

Is there a way to do the same sort of thing using SQL Server?

---

Related: [Oracle: Generate WHERE clause from resultset ids?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67952593/oracle-generate-where-clause-from-resultset-ids)

Comment: [STRING_AGG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this.

```
with a as (

  <my_query>

)
SELECT 'WHERE id IN (' +
  STRING_AGG(id, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY id) 
  + ')' as where_clause
FROM a
```

then you will get `WHERE id IN (1,2,3)`

If you want to get `WHERE id IN ('1','2','3')`
then you can change like following

```
SELECT 'WHERE id IN (''' +
      STRING_AGG(id, ''',''') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY id) 
      + ''')' as where_clause
FROM a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a normal `IN`

```sql
with a as (

  <my_query>

),
b as (

  <Other Query>

)
select *
from b
where b.id in (
  select a.id
  from a
);
```