# Group By inside Rtrim(Xmlagg (Xmlelement (e,element || ',')).extract ( '//text()' ).GetClobVal(), ',')

Tags: oracle, ansi-sql

I need to group values ​​inside a query using **(or not)** the command Rtrim(Xmlagg (Xmlelement (e,column || ',')).extract ( '//text()' ).GetClobVal(), ','), but *I can't find any literature where explain a way to group the data inside this command*. The code is very simple, as you can see below:

```
SELECT ID,
Rtrim(Xmlagg (Xmlelement (and, CONTRACTS || ',')).extract ( '//text()' ).GetClobVal(), ',') AS CONTRACTS
FROM TABLE_A
GROUP BY ID
```

The result in CONTRACTS is always repeated when the ID is found, thats ok, it´s working!

| ID | CONTRACTS |
| --- | --- |
| 876 | 1,1,1,2,3,3 |

But what I really need is this return:

| ID | CONTRACTS |
| --- | --- |
| 876 | 1,2,3 |

It´s not necessary to use the command Rtrim(Xmlagg (Xmlelement (e,column || ',')).extract ( '//text()' ).GetClobVal(), ','), instead, I just use to concatenate element with comma "," in the same column.

If anyone can help me, I would be very grateful!

Comment: Probably a duplicate  of https://stackoverflow.com/q/11510870/1509264

Comment: Note that RTRIM, Xmlagg etc are not ANSI SQL functions.

Answer (score 1):

If your values will fit into a `VARCHAR2` data type (rather than a `CLOB`) then you can use a nested sub-query to get the `DISTINCT` values for each `ID`:

```sql
SELECT ID,
       LISTAGG(contracts, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY contracts) AS CONTRACTS
FROM   ( SELECT DISTINCT id, contracts FROM TABLE_A)
GROUP BY ID
```

Or, from Oracle 19c, it is built-in to `LISTAGG`:

```sql
SELECT ID,
       LISTAGG(DISTINCT contracts, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY contracts) AS CONTRACTS
FROM   TABLE_A
GROUP BY ID
```

If you want a `CLOB` then you can use the same technique as the first query:

```sql
SELECT ID,
       Rtrim(
         Xmlagg(
           Xmlelement(name, CONTRACTS || ',')
           ORDER BY contracts
         ).extract ( '//text()' ).GetClobVal(),
         ','
       ) AS CONTRACTS
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT id, contracts FROM TABLE_A)
GROUP BY ID
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_a (id, contracts) AS
SELECT 876, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 876, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 876, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 876, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 876, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 876, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 876, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 876, 3 FROM DUAL;
```

All output:

> | ID | CONTRACTS |
> | --- | --- |
> | 876 | 1,2,3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e0bbd4d681c2acefac27d6a4123f3925)*

Comment: Thanks, it works fine! But now the memory heaper kick me out with this message: ) 04030. 00000 - "out of process memory when trying to allocate %s bytes (%s,%s)" *Cause: Operating system process private memory was exhausted.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to do all those operation in XML functions: [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3a4a786e7322bd8a5ad5ae3a7df40559)

```sql
SELECT--+ NO_XML_QUERY_REWRITE
  id,
  xmlquery(
    'string-join(distinct-values($R/R/X/text()),",")'
    passing 
        Xmlelement(
            R,
            Xmlagg(
                Xmlelement (X, CONTRACTS)
                order by CONTRACTS
            )) as R
    RETURNING CONTENT
  ) AS CONTRACTS
FROM TABLE_A
GROUP BY ID;
```

Full example with test data:

```sql
with table_a (id, contracts) AS (
SELECT 876, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 876, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 876, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 876, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 876, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 876, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 876, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 876, 3 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT--+ NO_XML_QUERY_REWRITE
  id,
  xmlquery(
    'string-join(distinct-values($R/R/X/text()),",")'
    passing 
        Xmlelement(
            R,
            Xmlagg(
                Xmlelement (X, CONTRACTS)
                order by CONTRACTS
            )) as R
    RETURNING CONTENT
  ) AS CONTRACTS
FROM TABLE_A
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: Thanks dudes, the querys sugest works fine, bouth! But I have another problem to fix: This one: Ocorreu um erro ao executar a operação solicitada:

ORA-04030: sem espaço de memória para processo durante tentativa de alocação de 4024 bytes (koh dur heap d,rworotdTransDeq)
04030. 00000 -  "out of process memory when trying to allocate %s bytes (%s,%s)"
*Cause:    Operating system process private memory was exhausted.
*Action:
Código de fornecedor 4030