# In Oracle how to distinctly listagg on 2 column level

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with data below:

```
emp_id  company_id  company_version_id  account_id  duplicate_account_id
174043265   10622557    1   201013278   101104723
174043265   10622557    1   201013278   200999888
174043265   10622557    1   201013278   203010306
174043265   10622557    1   201013278   205436979
174043265   10622557    1   201013278   205436980
174043265   10622557    1   201013293   101104723
174043265   10622557    1   201013293   200999888
174043265   10622557    1   201013293   203010306
174043265   10622557    1   201013293   205436979
174043265   10622557    1   201013293   205436980
```

In Oracle, how to achieve below:

```
emp_id  company_id  company_version_id  account_id  duplicate_account_id
174043265   10622557    1   201013278, 201013293    101104723, 200999888, 203010306, 205436979, 205436980
```

[image: Expected Result]

Code to create table and test out:

```
create table dummy_data AS
select 174043265 emp_id,  10622557 company_id,  1 company_version_id, 201013278 account_id,  101104723 duplicate_account_id from dual union all
select 174043265 emp_id,  10622557 company_id,  1 company_version_id, 201013278 account_id,  200999888 duplicate_account_id from dual union all
select 174043265 emp_id,  10622557 company_id,  1 company_version_id, 201013278 account_id,  203010306 duplicate_account_id from dual union all
select 174043265 emp_id,  10622557 company_id,  1 company_version_id, 201013278 account_id,  205436979 duplicate_account_id from dual union all
select 174043265 emp_id,  10622557 company_id,  1 company_version_id, 201013278 account_id,  205436980 duplicate_account_id from dual union all
select 174043265 emp_id,  10622557 company_id,  1 company_version_id, 201013293 account_id,  101104723 duplicate_account_id from dual union all
select 174043265 emp_id,  10622557 company_id,  1 company_version_id, 201013293 account_id,  200999888 duplicate_account_id from dual union all
select 174043265 emp_id,  10622557 company_id,  1 company_version_id, 201013293 account_id,  203010306 duplicate_account_id from dual union all
select 174043265 emp_id,  10622557 company_id,  1 company_version_id, 201013293 account_id,  205436979 duplicate_account_id from dual union all
select 174043265 emp_id,  10622557 company_id,  1 company_version_id, 201013293 account_id,  205436980 duplicate_account_id from dual
```

Would be great if the listagg length limitation is also handled (without truncating).

Thanks.

Comment: thanks @astentx, https://stackoverflow.com/a/24828742/2798218 answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

Saying that you use Oracle isn't enough - which **version** is it? Because, `listagg` supports `distinct` in recent versions:

```
SQL> select emp_id, company_id, company_version_id,
  2    listagg(distinct account_id, ', ') within group (order by account_id) account_id,
  3    listagg(distinct duplicate_account_id, ', ') within group (order by duplicate_account_id) duplicate_account_id
  4  from dummy_data
  5  group by emp_id, company_id, company_version_id;

    EMP_ID COMPANY_ID COMPANY_VERSION_ID ACCOUNT_ID                     DUPLICATE_ACCOUNT_ID
---------- ---------- ------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------------------
 174043265   10622557                  1 201013278, 201013293           101104723, 200999888, 203010306, 205436979, 205436980

SQL>
```

---

If your database doesn't support it, first find distinct values, then aggregate them:

```
SQL> with
  2  temp_acc as
  3    (select distinct emp_id, company_id, company_version_id, account_id
  4     from dummy_data
  5    ),
  6  temp_dup_acc as
  7    (select distinct emp_id, company_id, company_version_id, duplicate_account_id
  8     from dummy_data
  9    ),
 10  agg_acc as
 11    (select a.emp_id, a.company_id, a.company_version_id,
 12       listagg(a.account_id, ', ') within group (order by a.account_id) account_id
 13     from temp_acc a
 14     group by a.emp_id, a.company_id, a.company_version_id
 15    ),
 16  agg_dup as
 17    (select a.emp_id, a.company_id, a.company_version_id,
 18       listagg(a.duplicate_account_id, ', ') within group (order by a.duplicate_account_id) duplicate_account_id
 19     from temp_dup_acc a
 20     group by a.emp_id, a.company_id, a.company_version_id
 21    )
 22  select a.emp_id, a.company_id, a.company_version_id, a.account_id, d.duplicate_account_id
 23  from agg_acc a join agg_dup d on a.emp_id = d.emp_id
 24                                     and a.company_id = d.company_id
 25                                     and a.company_version_id = d.company_version_id;

    EMP_ID COMPANY_ID COMPANY_VERSION_ID ACCOUNT_ID                     DUPLICATE_ACCOUNT_ID
---------- ---------- ------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------------------
 174043265   10622557                  1 201013278, 201013293           101104723, 200999888, 203010306, 205436979, 205436980

SQL>
```