# Get distinct letters in a string in order of occurance

Tags: regex, plsql

I am working in PL/SQL and I need to get the distinct letters within a string returned in the order first found. I can do this by iterating over the string multiple times but can I do it in one regex instead?

Here are some examples:

- 'aa' should return 'a'.
- 'ab' should return 'ab'.
- 'aabbcc' should return 'abc'.
- 'abccba' should return 'abc'.

Comment: No, oracle regex does not have look around support.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LISTAGG in Oracle to return distinct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510870/listagg-in-oracle-to-return-distinct-values)

Comment: I don't think I can make LISTAGG work without cutting up the string into single characters. My string is a single variable as opposed to a collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
select regexp_replace('aabbxcc','(.)\1+','\1') from dual
```

- `.` refers to any character
- `()` places that character in a group.
- `\1` refers to the previous match
- `+` means the previous match occurs one or more times

In other words the regular expression looks for repeated characters where repeated means the same character appearing twice or three times or more in succession, e.g. `aa` or `aaa` or `aaaa`.

The replace string refers to the character matched by the group which is a single character. Hence the [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REGEXP_REPLACE.html#GUID-EA80A33C-441A-4692-A959-273B5A224490) function will replace repeated characters with only a single occurrence of that character and non-repeated characters will be kept as they are.

Refer to this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pcj3LVsk).

Of-course the above will not work with your last example of `abccba` for which you want to get `abc`. I don't think that can be achieved with regular expressions at all. Since you say you are using PL/SQL, then perhaps repeat the above in a `while` loop until the REGEXP_REPLACE does not change the source at all.

Comment: Your regex expression is much more succinct than what I had created. I was hopeful for a single (non-iterative) approach, but not everything is possible.