# Java remove duplicate values from result set

Tags: java

I have requirement to remove the duplicate values from result set based on some unique identifier.

I need to remove the duplicates from the result set.

```
  while(resultSet.next())
  {     
   int seqNo = resultSet.getInt("SEQUENCE_NO");

   String tableName = resultSet.getString("TABLE_NAME");

   String columnName = resultSet.getString("COLUMN_NAME");

  String filter = resultSet.getString("FILTER");

 }
```

from the above iteration, i m getting 2 rows from result set. There is same seq no,same table name, different columnname, same filter.

```
1 PRODUCTFEES CHARGETYPE PRODUCTID

1 PRODUCTFEES PRODUCTCODE PRODUCTID
```

My requirement is to remove the duplicate table name, duplicate seq no, duplicate filter.

I want to get output something below,

```
1 PRODUCTFEES CHARGETYPE PRODUCTCODE PRODUCTID
```

Comment: @AchintyaJha most probably a `java.sql.ResultSet`, the result of a JDBC query.

Comment: Will you get same seq no,same table name, different columnname, same filter everytime?? for every query??

Comment: Do you want to remove the duplicates from the result or do you want to delete them from the database? Second, does your query only return duplicates or does it return other information as well? You must provide further details!

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, but why not just use SELECT DISTINCT or GROUP BY and stop them ever getting *into* the result set?

Comment: @home He isn't likely to be wanting to delete things from the schema :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the example you provide, it seems like you want to output all distinct values for each column indidivually (there are 4 columns in the table, but you output 5 values).

Being the question tagged `java`, an approach you could take would be using an implementation of `Set` for each of the columns, so that duplicates won't get through. Then output all the elements of each `Set`.

```
LinkedHashSet[] sets = new LinkedHashSet[]{
    new LinkedHashSet(), 
    new LinkedHashSet(),
    new LinkedHashSet(),
    new LinkedHashSet() };

while(resultSet.next()) {     
    sets[0].add(resultSet.getInt("SEQUENCE_NO"));
    sets[1].add(resultSet.getString("TABLE_NAME")););
    sets[2].add(resultSet.getString("COLUMN_NAME"));
    sets[3].add(resultSet.getString("FILTER"));
}

StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
for (LinkedHashSet set : sets) {
    // append to buf all elements of each set
}
```

But it might be simpler to address this from the very same SQL query and just make `SELECT DISTINCT columnX` for each of the columns and output the result without further manipulation. Or use an aggregation function that will concatenate all distinct values. The implementation will be highly dependent on the DBMS you're using ([`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for MySQL, [`LISTAGG`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm) for Oracle, ...). This would be a similar question for Oracle: [How to use Oracle's LISTAGG function with a unique filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7355095/851811)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the different outputs I'd say, that you not just need to remove duplicates, but also reorder the data from the duplicates.

In that case you need to fill a new data-array (or similar structure) in the `while(resultSet.next())`, and after that loop over the newly arranged data-object and output accordingly.

In Meta-Lang this would be as follows:

```
while resultset.next()
    if newdata-array has unique key
        add column-name to found entry in newdata-array
    else
        create new entry in newdata-array with column-name

while newdata-array.next()
    output seq, table-name
    while entry.column-names.next()
        output column-name
    output product-id
```