# How to use Oracle's LISTAGG function for two columns?

Tags: oracle

I found very nice article about [comma separated list of values in Oracle](https://www.salvis.com/blog/2012/12/23/building-comma-separated-values-with-oracle-sql/).

I wanted to try it, but with two columns instead of one, in a such way, that for data:

```
+---+---+---+
| 1 | a | A |
| 1 | a | B |
| 1 | b | A |
| 1 | b | B |
| 1 | c | A |
| 1 | c | B |
| 2 | a | A |
| 2 | a | B |
| 2 | a | C |
| 2 | b | A |
| 2 | b | B |
| 2 | b | C |
+---+---+---+
```

I wanted to have the result:

```
+---+---------+---------+
| 1 | a, b, c | A, B    |
| 2 | a, b    | A, B, C |
+---+---------+---------+
```

First problem I had, was to use `over` part at all...

Even, when I saw [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions089.htm) and multiple examples, f.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355095/how-to-use-oracles-listagg-function-with-a-unique-filter).

I was not able to get over `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression` problem with:

```sql
with demotable as
(
  select 1 v1, 'a' v2, 'A' v3 from dual union all
  select 1 v1, 'a' v2, 'B' v3 from dual union all
  select 1 v1, 'b' v2, 'A' v3 from dual union all
  select 1 v1, 'b' v2, 'B' v3 from dual union all
  select 1 v1, 'c' v2, 'A' v3 from dual union all
  select 1 v1, 'c' v2, 'B' v3 from dual union all
  select 2 v1, 'a' v2, 'A' v3 from dual union all
  select 2 v1, 'a' v2, 'B' v3 from dual union all
  select 2 v1, 'a' v2, 'C' v3 from dual union all
  select 2 v1, 'b' v2, 'A' v3 from dual union all
  select 2 v1, 'b' v2, 'B' v3 from dual union all
  select 2 v1, 'b' v2, 'C' v3 from dual
)
select v1 
     , LISTAGG (
          v3, ', '
       ) within group (
          order by v3
       ) over (
          partition by v1
       ) AS v3_list
  from demotable
 group by v1
;
```

which based on other examples should be working.

First solution, that came into my mind is not working

```sql
with demotable as ( ... )
select v1 
     , LISTAGG (
          v2, ', '
       ) within group (
          order by v2
       ) AS v2_list
     , LISTAGG (
          v3, ', '
       ) within group (
          order by v3
       ) AS v3_list
  from demotable
 group by v1
;
```

because it returns:

```
+---+------------------+------------------+
| 1 | a, a, b, b, c, c | A, A, A, B, B, B |
| 2 | a, a, a, b, b, b | A, A, B, B, C, C |
+---+------------------+------------------+
```

My Oracle version is 12c.

```
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
```

I found only the ugly solution with select from select:

```sql
with demotable as ( ... )
select v1
     , LISTAGG (
          v2, ', '
       ) within group (
          order by v2
       ) AS v2_list
     , v3_list
  from (
    select v1
         , v2
         , LISTAGG (
              v3, ', '
           ) within group (
              order by v3
           ) AS v3_list
      from demotable
     group by v1, v2
) group by v1, v3_list
;
```

Someone who deleted his comment recommended to use `group by` for all columns, which lead me to this solution:

```sql
with demotable as ( ... )
select distinct v1 
     , LISTAGG (
          v2, ', '
       ) WITHIN GROUP (
          ORDER BY v2
       ) over (
          partition by v1, v3
       ) AS v2_list
     , LISTAGG (
          v3, ', '
       ) WITHIN GROUP (
          ORDER BY v3
       ) over (
          partition by v1, v2
       ) AS v2_list
  from demotable
 group by v1, v2, v3
;
```

but  I'm not fan of `distinct` if not necessary.

**edit 2022:**

As you can see, I used to do union all, in 2020 I found out it can be done using `json_table`:

```sql
select * from json_table(
    '[ ' ||
    '  {v1: 1, v2: "a", v3: "A"}' ||
    ', {v1: 1, v2: "a", v3: "B"}' ||
    ', {v1: 1, v2: "b", v3: "A"}' ||
    ', {v1: 1, v2: "b", v3: "B"}' ||
    ', {v1: 1, v2: "c", v3: "A"}' ||
    ', {v1: 1, v2: "c", v3: "B"}' ||
    ', {v1: 2, v2: "a", v3: "A"}' ||
    ', {v1: 2, v2: "a", v3: "B"}' ||
    ', {v1: 2, v2: "a", v3: "C"}' ||
    ', {v1: 2, v2: "b", v3: "A"}' ||
    ', {v1: 2, v2: "b", v3: "B"}' ||
    ', {v1: 2, v2: "b", v3: "C"}' ||
    ']', '$[*]' 
    columns v1 number path '$.v1'
          , v2 varchar2(20) path '$.v2'
          , v3 varchar2(1) path '$.v3'
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this really nice [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8478/16768)

```
select v1 
,RTRIM(
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           (listagg(v3,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY v3) ), 
           '([^,]*)(,\1)+($|,)', 
           '\1\3'),
         ',') as v3group
  ,RTRIM(
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           (listagg(v2,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY v2) ), 
           '([^,]*)(,\1)+($|,)', 
           '\1\3'),
         ',') as v2group
  from demotable
  GROUP BY v1
;
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7/4900)

Comment: +1, because it's working, but it is not really clear to me, how that works and in such case I'd prefer distinct even, when I do not like it...

Comment: @Betlista While regular expressions are obnoxious,there is another solution using a smart CROSS JOIN with a DISTINCT table,but that too is not straightforward.  http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/697/16768

Comment: I prefer this one at the end, because there is just one list of attributes, that needs to be maintained (the one from comment [with cross join] is more unclear).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your requirement correctly, I think this does what you're after:

```
with demotable as (select 1 v1, 'a' v2, 'A' v3 from dual union all
                   select 1 v1, 'a' v2, 'B' v3 from dual union all
                   select 1 v1, 'b' v2, 'A' v3 from dual union all
                   select 1 v1, 'b' v2, 'B' v3 from dual union all
                   select 1 v1, 'c' v2, 'A' v3 from dual union all
                   select 1 v1, 'c' v2, 'B' v3 from dual union all
                   select 2 v1, 'a' v2, 'A' v3 from dual union all
                   select 2 v1, 'a' v2, 'B' v3 from dual union all
                   select 2 v1, 'a' v2, 'C' v3 from dual union all
                   select 2 v1, 'b' v2, 'A' v3 from dual union all
                   select 2 v1, 'b' v2, 'B' v3 from dual union all
                   select 2 v1, 'b' v2, 'C' v3 from dual),
           res as (select v1,
                          case when row_number() over (partition by v1, v2 order by v3) = 1 then v2 end v2,
                          case when row_number() over (partition by v1, v3 order by v2) = 1 then v3 end v3
                   from   demotable)
select v1,
       listagg(v2, ', ') within group (order by v2) v2_list,
       listagg(v3, ', ') within group (order by v2) v3_list
from   res
group by v1;

        V1 V2_LIST    V3_LIST   
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 a, b, c    A, B      
         2 a, b       A, B, C
```

The res subquery is needed to only display one instance of each value in the v2 and v3 columns, so that you have a list of distinct values to be passed into each listagg.