# Oracle SQL query: How do I combine these results?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to combine these allegedly duplicated (actually not) entries into unique ones under the group of property id(PTY_ID), this is the results:

[image: here]

and below is my query codes:

```
SELECT distinct P.PTY_ID, (P.PTY_UNITNUM||' '||P.PTY_STREET||', '
       ||P.PTY_SUBURB||', '||P.PTY_CITY||' '||P.PTY_POSTCODE) address,
       T.P_type_name, F.FEAT_name
FROM  property P, PROPERTY_TYPE T, feature F, property_FEATURE K
WHERE  P.P_TYPE_ID = T.P_TYPE_ID
AND   K.feat_id = F.feat_id
AND   K.pty_id = P.pty_id
ORDER BY  p.pty_id;
```

To be more precise, I want to show one unique property entry showing many features. How can I do that?

By the way I am using oracle 11g. So I tried LISTAGG, but did not work out quite well...

## [UPDATE]

I just tried to use LISTAGG like this:

```
select distinct P.PTY_ID, (P.PTY_UNITNUM||' '||P.PTY_STREET||', '
      ||P.PTY_SUBURB||', '||P.PTY_CITY||' '||P.PTY_POSTCODE) address,
      T.P_type_name, LISTAGG(F.FEAT_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 
      P.PTY_ID) AS FEATURES
from property P, PROPERTY_TYPE T, feature F, property_FEATURE K
where P.P_TYPE_ID = T.P_TYPE_ID
and K.feat_id = F.feat_id
and K.pty_id = P.pty_id
group by P.PTY_ID, P.PTY_UNITNUM, P.PTY_STREET, P.PTY_SUBURB, P.PTY_CITY, 
P.PTY_POSTCODE, T.P_type_name
order by p.pty_id;
```

I got this error saying:"FROM keyword not found where expected". The error happens in the line "`T.P_type_name, LISTAGG(F.FEAT_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY P.PTY_ID) AS FEATURES`"

Comment: What does "not work out quite well" mean?  I would guess that you should use `listagg`.  I don't know what problem you encountered and I don't know what you tried so I don't know whether `listagg` is the wrong approach or whether you did something wrong or whether your question needs more clarification.

Comment: Check this listagg implementation and post what have u tried using listagg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355095/how-to-use-oracles-listagg-function-with-a-unique-filter

Comment: @JustinCave oops sorry forgot to mention that.. I got a "FROM keyword not found where expected" warning in the result board

Comment: OK.  So you tried some unknown piece of code and got a syntax error.  It would be helpful to post the code you actually tried along with the full error stack.  Specifying the actual results that you want would also be helpful.

Comment: @JustinCave yeah just edited. Pls have a look

Comment: Please post data as formatted test, [not  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing 'AS' before 'FEATURES' ...

```
LISTAGG(F.FEAT_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY P.PTY_ID) AS FEATURES

LISTAGG(F.FEAT_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY P.PTY_ID) FEATURES
```

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.PTY_ID,
  (P.PTY_UNITNUM
  ||' '
  ||P.PTY_STREET
  ||', '
  ||P.PTY_SUBURB
  ||', '
  ||P.PTY_CITY
  ||' '
  ||P.PTY_POSTCODE) address,
  T.P_type_name,
  LISTAGG(F.FEAT_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY P.PTY_ID) FEATURES
FROM property P,
  PROPERTY_TYPE T,
  feature F,
  property_FEATURE K
WHERE P.P_TYPE_ID = T.P_TYPE_ID
AND K.feat_id     = F.feat_id
AND K.pty_id      = P.pty_id
GROUP BY P.PTY_ID,
  P.PTY_UNITNUM,
  P.PTY_STREET,
  P.PTY_SUBURB,
  P.PTY_CITY,
  P.PTY_POSTCODE,
  T.P_type_name
ORDER BY p.pty_id;
```

Comment: you are basically just copying and pasting the whole code: with or without, it works the same

Comment: It would help if you share ddl of all tables involved please.