# How to return the result in Map in PL/SQL?

Tags: java, database, plsql

I want to return a map to my Java code from a stored procedure. The results from PL/SQL in a Map format like **Map<key, List>**. Is it possible to return data like that?

I have returned the whole data in a string and from java class I have used split logic to split the data and saved them in proper fields. Like an example:

```java
String[] lines = resultString.split(System.lineSeparator());  List<MessageVO> resultPerList = new ArrayList<>();
  for (String line : lines) {
          MessageVO message = new MessageVO();
          String[] fieldArray = line.split(":", 0);
         String field= fieldArray[0];
          message.setField(field);
         resultPerList.add(message);
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried to do so?

Comment: I have returned the whole data in a string and from java class I have used split logic to split the data and saved them in proper fields. Like an example,

`String[] lines = resultString.split(System.lineSeparator()); 
List<MessageVO> resultPerList = new ArrayList<>(); 
for (String line : lines) { 
        MessageVO message = new MessageVO(); 
        String[] fieldArray = line.split(":", 0);
        String field= fieldArray[0]; 
        message.setField(field);
        resultPerList.add(message);
}`

No idea that how can I split the resultString(returned OUT parameter) to a map.

Answer (score 0):

If you like PL/SQL and the resulting lists are small, your solution (structuring data in SQL) is good. In PL/SQL you can take advantage of [the listagg statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355095/how-to-use-oracles-listagg-function-with-a-unique-filter)
Here is functional sample:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class sasafd {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String resultString = "key1:valuea:valueb:valuec"
            + System.lineSeparator()
            + "key2:valuea:valueb:valuec";

        String[] lines = resultString.split(System.lineSeparator());
        Map<String, List<String>> resultMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        for (String line : lines) {
            String[] fieldArray = line.split(":", 0);
            for (String value : fieldArray)
                if (resultMap.containsKey(fieldArray[0])) {
                    resultMap.get(fieldArray[0]).add(value);
                } else {
                    resultMap.put(fieldArray[0], new LinkedList<String>());
                }
        }       
        System.out.println(convertWithStream(resultMap));
    }

    public static String convertWithStream(Map<String, List<String>> map) {
        String mapAsString = map.keySet().stream().map(key -> key + "=" + map.get(key))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "{", "}"));
        return mapAsString;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{key1=[valuea, valueb, valuec], key2=[valuea, valueb, valuec]}
```

If you like more tabular data, from DB you can use thoughts from this code:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class sasafd {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] resultSet =
             {{"key1","valuea"},{"key1","valueb"},{"key1","valuec"}
              ,{"key2","valuea"},{"key2","valueb"},{"key2","valuec"}};

        Map<String, List<String>> resultMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        for (String[] line : resultSet) {
                if (resultMap.containsKey(line[0])) {
                    resultMap.get(line[0]).add(line[1]);
                } else {
                    resultMap.put(line[0], new LinkedList<String>());
                    resultMap.get(line[0]).add(line[1]);
                }
        }       
        System.out.println(convertWithStream(resultMap));
    }

    public static String convertWithStream(Map<String, List<String>> map) {
        String mapAsString = map.keySet().stream().map(key -> key + "=" + map.get(key))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "{", "}"));
        return mapAsString;
    }
}
```

You can also try ORM. If you dislike colon-separated text from PL/SQL you can also use XML, JSON, ...

JDBC doesn't support Map results.